# Sorting XML parent nodes by the value of child node

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT. Please help me with this.
    Sort the EmploymentUpdateRequests for each co-worker by ValidFrom of the Field FORNAMN Ascending and write the EmploymentUpdateRequests in the XML file.

I am only able to sort based on employee number which will group all the same employee number in order but unable to further sort based on validfrom in ascending order using xslt.

Please help.

```
Input XML:

<EmploymentUpdateRequests>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020410</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Roberts</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="LANGUAGE" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>el</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020413</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Roberts</Value>
    </FieldValue>
</Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020413</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-11-29</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-11-29</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-11-29</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-11-29</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Robert</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020410</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-18</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-17</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-18</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-18</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-17</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-18</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-17</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Roberts</Value>
    </FieldValue>
   </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020410</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Roberts</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
</EmploymentUpdateRequests>
```

Expected Output:

```
<EmploymentUpdateRequests>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020410</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Roberts</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020410</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Roberts</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="LANGUAGE" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-18</ValidUntil>
      <Value>el</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020410</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-18</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-17</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-18</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-18</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-17</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-18</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-17</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Roberts</Value>
    </FieldValue>
   </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020413</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Roberts</Value>
    </FieldValue>
</Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0017</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>020413</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-11-29</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-11-29</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-11-29</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Nicoleta Geta</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="EFTERNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-11-29</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Juenker Robert</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
</EmploymentUpdateRequests>
```

This xml needs to be sorted in the way expected in the above example. Could some please share the xslt sample for this.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your current XSLT? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EmploymentUpdateRequests">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="EmploymentUpdateRequest"
                group-by="descendant::FieldValue[@Name ='FORNAMN']">
                <xsl:sort select="descendant::FieldValue[@Name ='FORNAMN']/ValidFrom" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for the reply. I am getting the error, JAXP: Error during transformation - Could not find function: current-group; Line#: 13; Column#: 56

Comment: Which processor you are using? Are you using JAXP.

Comment: Please use Saxon-PE 9.5.1.7, It's working perfectly from my side.

Comment: I have changed it from JAXP to Saxon. Its gettign executed, but sorting is not happening. I am getting results like below.                                               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  0017
  020410
  
    
      2016-10-19
      2016-10-18
      2016-10-19
    
    
      2016-10-19
      2016-10-18
      Nicoleta Geta Sorina Dana Vale

Comment: I got below result is this perfect for you.    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">

      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-01-19</ValidFrom>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">

      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">

      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-10-19</ValidFrom>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">

      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-11-29</ValidFrom>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">

      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2016-12-18</ValidFrom>

Comment: I have sorted based on **FieldValue Name="FORNAMN"** and **ValidFrom** date value

Comment: Yes, praveensingh.soft@gmail.com

Comment: Hi, I added the below logic in the above code and it is working as expected. Thanks for the support.                                                                                               
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
   <xsl:sort select="EmploymentNo" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

Comment: Hello All, This sorting is working only for the nodes with child node <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">, but few parents nodes do not have <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String"> and it is not grouping them,and skipping those records in the output. I want those xml nodes also without FORNAMN in teh end. i tried if chose and otherwise condition but it is not working. can someone please help